# UIButton Background image is not set from Singleton Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, swift-dictionary

again.

I've just finished a singleton example of a Dictionary with the following code
at the file `Recipes.swift`

```
 static let sharedInstance = Recipes()

var imagesOfChef = [Int : chefImages]()
 struct chefImages {
        var objidChef: String!
        var imageChef: UIImage!
    }
```

And when a process is finished i have this code

```
let singleton = Recipes.sharedInstance
singleton.imagesOfChef = self.imagesOfChef
```

So the `singleton` has the same dictionary as the `imagesOfChef` has.

On the next view i want to access all the data of the Dictionary and set a background image of the button with one of the images that the Dictionary has.
So in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I have the following code

```
let test = userPointer.objectId
    let otherReferenceToTheSameSingleton = Recipes.sharedInstance




for i in 0...otherReferenceToTheSameSingleton.imagesOfChef.count - 1  {
    print(otherReferenceToTheSameSingleton.imagesOfChef[i]!.objidChef) //it prints the object id's of the Chef normally

    if otherReferenceToTheSameSingleton.imagesOfChef[i]!.objidChef  == test! {
        print("done")
        print(otherReferenceToTheSameSingleton.imagesOfChef[i]!.imageChef)
        cell.avatarOutlet.setImage(otherReferenceToTheSameSingleton.imagesOfChef[i]!.imageChef, forState: .Normal) //but it doesnt set the Image as a background

    }

}
```

So when the object id of the Chef matches the object id that is inside the Dictionary i want to set as background the image that is in the same row.

But it doesn't!

Although when the `if statement` is correct if you see i try to print the image and i get

```
<UIImage: 0x1582c9b50>, {60, 60}
```

How is it possible to set this image as background??!?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your button created programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Button type custom if it is created programmatically

```
 let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
```

If it is from Stroyboard change the type there.

Comment: Oh.. yes that was the solution!